# Error when trying to execute kylin.sh start in HDP Sandbox 2.6

Tags: hadoop, hive, kylin

I installed Apache Kylin, following the official installation guide http://kylin.apache.org/docs/install/index.html, in HDP sandbox 2.6

When I run the script, *$KYLIN_HOME/bin/kylin.sh start*, I got the error below:

[image]

What can I do to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check if Hive service is up in your ambari, when Hive service is down Kylin cannot find it and gives the error. Check for .bash_profile as well. When those two issues are addressed kylin should be able to find location of hive dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Kylin uses the *find-hive-dependency.sh* script to setup the CLASSPATH. This script uses a Hive CLI  command (I test it with `beeline`) to query Hive env vars and extract the CLASSPATH from them.

`beeline` connect to Hive using the properties at *kylin_hive_conf.xml* but for some reason (probably due to the Hive version included in HDP 2.6) some of the loaded Hive properties cannot be set when the connection is stablished.

The Hive properties that causes the issue can be discarded for connecting to Hive to query the CLASSPATH, so, to fix this issue:

1. Edit *$KYLIN_HOME/conf/kylin.properties* and set `kylin.source.hive.client=beeline`
2. Open the *find-hive-dependency.sh* script, go to line 34 aprox and modify the line

   `hive_env=${beeline_shell} ${hive_conf_properties} ${beeline_params} --outputformat=dsv -e "set;" 2>&1 | grep 'env:CLASSPATH'`

   Just remove `${hive_conf_properties}`

Check Hive depedencies have been configured by running the command *find-hive-dependency.sh*.

Now *$KYLIN_HOME/bin/kylin.sh start* should works.